# mapping two case classes in scala on Lagom

Tags: java, keymap, api, scala, couchdb

I am a beginner with scala/Lagom, can someone help me with the following issue :

I am trying to creat an Api for fields of products, in order to do that : I need to map case classes extending to a trait named SmartJsonField with other case classes that are created for the Api which have a trait named Field

like this :

```
trait SmartJsonField {
    type Typ

    def name: String

    def isRequired: Boolean

    def validations: Set[ValidationKey]

   
  }

case class Str(name: String, isRequired: Boolean = true, regex: Option[String], minLength: Option[Int], maxLength: Option[Int], validations: Set[ValidationKey] = Set()) extends SmartJsonField {

      type Typ = String

      lazy val optRegex: Option[Regex] = regex.map(_.r)
```

I want to map it with classes from this trait

```
sealed trait Field 
  {
    def isRequired : Boolean
    def validations: Set[ValidationKeyApi]
  }


  case class FieldString(required : Boolean,
                         min : Option[Int], max : Option[Int],  regex: Option[String],  validations: Set[ValidationKeyApi]= Set()) extends Field // a field that takes a String value
{
  override def isRequired = required
}
```

Here is how I do the mapping :

```
def recursiveFieldMapping( fieldSchema : SmartJsonField) : Field = {
    fieldSchema match {
      
      case field: SmartJsonField.Str =>
        FieldString(field.isRequired, field.minLength, field.maxLength, field.regex, field.validations)
      
    }
  }
```

It is working for all the parameters except **field.validations**, because it is not from the same type :

```
required : Set[ValidationKeyApi] 
found : Set[ValidationKey]
```

here are the case classes ValidationKey and ValidationKeyApi :

```
  case class ValidationKey(key: String, priority: Option[Int] = None)
```

```
  case class ValidationKeyApi(key: String, priority: Option[Int] = None)
```

As you can see it is same thing but since I cannot import them ( Lagom Framework) I don't see how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution 30 minutes after posting it :

I just needed o map the new case class ValiationKeyApi with the case class ValidationKey like this

```
 FieldString(field.isRequired, field.minLength, field.maxLength, field.regex ,field.validations.map { ValidationKey =>
          ValidationKeyApi(ValidationKey.key, ValidationKey.priority)
        })
```